# How to drop and recreate Indexes inside PLSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

In PLSQL stored procedure, I would like to drop indexes and truncate the table 
before inserting data into the table. Then I want to recreate the indexes afterwards . What is the best way of achieving this?

I need something similar like this

```
Begin:

Truncate Table
Drop index1
Drop  index2

loop
--- other code
Insert data
commit;
end loop;

Create index1
Create index2

End;
```

Comment: Use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and move the `COMMIT` outside the loop.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide some sample code.

Comment: i think `commit` is unnecessary, DB should commit transactions before DDL statements execution.

Comment: Does 'commit' effect anything?

Comment: it commits your  "Insert data", but if you miss commit, the result will be the same. DB, I guess Oracle in your case, will autocommit your transaction before create index DDL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't run DDL directly in PL/SQL.

The best approach is to use the Oracle built-in `DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT()`. It's covered in the docs [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#ARPLS73238). But basically:

```
begin
    DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('drop index index1')
    DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('drop index index2')
    DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('truncate table your_table')
    ....
```

Note that the commands are *strings* not SQL.

---

If you're inserting enough data to make it worthwhile dropping and re-creating the indexes then you probably want set operations rather than doing it in a loop. Set operations work on chunks of data rather then individual rows. Quite what approach is appropriate depends on how much data you have.

> "I want to insert data from staging table and then joining with other table"

So the most efficient route is likely to be

```
 insert into your_table
 select /*+ append */  ....
 from staging_table
      join other_table
      on ...
```

However, depending on your definition of "huge" you may need to use a PL/SQL bulk operation, with a FORALL insertion. That would require reading from your staging table in chunks, so it would entail a loop. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS01205)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on Set Operation?

Comment: I want to insert data from staging table and then joining with other table and finally inserting into Main table. Size of data is sometime high and sometime huge that depends on staging data.

Comment: I will try this approach. Thanks APC

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm) , specifically, [execute immediate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm), based on your requirements:

```
Begin:

execute immediate 'truncate table statement';
execute immediate 'DROP index statement';

loop
--- other code
Insert data
commit;
end loop;

execute immediate 'Create index1 statement';
execute immediate 'Create index2 statement';

End;
```

Comment: Thanks. drop and then create index will be good or unusable and then rebuild?

Comment: That depends on your size and type of data. Most of the time you need to benchmark that and decide. One case this approach is useful, is when your index causing insert/update to take longer time than dropping and recreating.

Comment: Actually I was inserting data using "Append" hint. So wanted to remove index.

Comment: Still, the size of the data and the resources impact the decision. You need to benchmark your approach (i.e., you need to run both and see the gain/loss difference)

Comment: In your Answer you mentioned "Statement". Is the syntax same as we normally create index.

Comment: It's the sql statement you want to run inside PL/SQL block. For example, if the table name is `table1`, to runcate it would be `execute immediate 'truncate table table1';`